# REGEX - Letters and symbols (C#)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regexp to match strings that matches strings starting with letters, next goes only one point, letters and underscores, and ends with some more letters (but not underscore).

**Examples:**

- ABC.PROCEDURE_INSERT_USER
- ZXYSQWE.PROCEDURE_LIST_PRODUCTS_COD_PROD_PRICE

My regex:

```
/^[A-Za-z]*\\.?[A-Za-z_]*(?=A-Za-z_)/
```

doesn't work..

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what have you tried. SO is a service to help those try to learn, no code generating service. That's why you have to show some efforts of your own, although the problem isn't complicated.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'll edit now. 
I have no idea to make regex, I have very simple examples but my question requires a complicated regex.
Really, sorry.

This is my regex:
/^[A-Za-z]*\\.?[A-Za-z_]*(?=A-Za-z_)/ (but don't works)

Comment: Is it a valid string: `A.____B`? And this one: `A_._B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help:

```
(?:^[a-zA-Z]*\\.[a-zA-Z_]*[a-zA-Z]$)
```

Start with a letter, then a dot, any combination of letters and underscore, and finish with a letter.

Instead checking if there is no underscore at the end, you know that always will be a letter. Its simplier to read.

You can see the regex test (with fixed issues you find) here:
[Regex101.com - Test](https://regex101.com/r/fD8sB4/1)

Comment: I use your code with a little modification:

`^[a-zA-Z]*\\.[a-zA-Z_]*[a-zA-Z]`

(In the point, one \ show me an error)

This works 99% perfect, but accept an underscore at the end.

Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Try this one. `(?:^[a-zA-Z]*\\.[a-zA-Z_]*[a-zA-Z]$)` The error in code is because you forgot to escape some caracters. I put only the REGEX. I tried checked again and fix the 1% error haha

Comment: Please give me some feedback if you tried my fixed solution, I also added the regex101 test. Regards,

Comment: Oh, I see, I forgot the ?: and $,
Now works 100% perfect, thank you very much! :D